# How do you identify if a domain in Freebase is either a commons/base?

Tags: freebase, mql

I see that the relationship between topics in Freebase start as follows:

/user/foo/...
/music/album/...
/base/talships/...

Should I just check if the relationship starts with the word "base" or "user" in which case the domain is not a commons domain? Thus, if it starts with any word other than "base" or "user" then it is a commons domain.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general you can tell that something is a user domain or a base just from looking at the ID. However the most reliable way to do it is in MQL like this:

```
{
  "id": "/music/album",
  "/type/type/domain": {
    "/freebase/domain_profile/category": [{
      "id": null
    }]
  }
}​
```

Any domain that has the category `/category/commons` is a Freebase commons domain.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I have the quad-dump of Freebase and in that if I look at a property, I would like to know if the domain is either a base or a user domain. So I asked if we can look at the first entry in the path and then determine. So, I shall use this technique then. I have a simple question then - if both user and base domains belong to non-common domains, then what is the difference between the user and base domains? If the user domains are those created by users, what would be the base domain then?

Comment: Okay, in the quad dumps you can rely on looking at the prefix. In the rare event that something has both a commons ID and a /user or /base ID it would default to the commons ID in the dumps. The reason for both /user and /base domains is historical. When Freebase first came out it only had commons domains (shared by everyone) and user domains (developed by one user). Several years later Freebase created the concept of a base which was not quite a commons but something which could be shared by a group of like-minded users. In the graph they're mostly the same but they served different purposes.